# diff images between 2 servers

Tags: php, linux, diff

I have 2 servers serv1 and serv2 and need to compare the images in those 2 servers to detect which files are missing or has been modified.

So far I have 3 options:

**- Create an API using PHP**

- I created an API file that will return all the images in serv1/www/app/images/
- get the modification time of each images
- return the result as json
- output is something like this: { 'path/to/file' : 123232433422 }
- I fetch that in serv2, decode then merge the array to the images in serv2/www/app/images
- get the array_diff, works fine

cons: 
- takes a lot of time (fetching, decoding, merging, looping, comparison... )

**- Use rsync**

- Dry run to get the list of images that is existing in serv1 but is missing or modified in serv2 (very fast :))

cons:

- apache can't run ssh because it's not authorized to access ~/.ssh/
- would need to give apache permission but my client doesn't want it
- so in short, i cannot use anything that would require permission

**- maybe I could use some library or vendor but I doubt my client would allow me. If it can be shell script or a php built in function, I'll do it as long as it's possible.**

So my question is if there is another way to fetch the images and modification date of those images without requiring authentication? My first solution is okay if it can be optimized cause if the array is too large, it takes a lot of time.

I hope the solution can be done in PHP, or Shell script.

Please help give me more options. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install utility `md5deep` (or `sha1deep`) on both servers.

Execute `md5deep` on first server and save result to text file:

```
user@server1> md5deep -l -r mydir > server1.txt
```

Result file would look like this:

```
e7c3fcf5ad7583012379ec49e9a47b28  .\a\file1.php
2ef76c2ecaefba21b395c6b0c6af7314  .\b\file2.txt
45e19bb4b38d529d6310946966f4df12  .\c\file3.bin
...
```

Then, copy file `server1.txt` to second server and run `md5deep` in negative matching mode:

```
md5deep -l -r -X server1.txt mydir
```

This will print checksums and names of all files on second server which are different from first server.

Alternatively, you can compare text files created by `md5deep -l -r dir` yourself using diff or similar utility.

Last note - it may be easier to simply run `md5deep -l -r mydir | gzip > md5deep.txt.gz` in cron on each server, such that you have ready to compare filelist with checksums on each server (gzipped so it is fast to fetch).